# Detect Which Cell a User is in With Custom Table View Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nsindexpath

I have a custom tableViewCell with two (2) textViews for a user to type in. I want to detect which tableView row the user is in. I tried:

```
let currentIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!

let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(currentIndexPath) as! Test2TableViewCell
```

and Xcode gives me the error, `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` which, to me, means that the app can't find the selected row. I'm assuming that when a user types in a textView on top of a tableViewCell, the app doesn't see you tapping on the actual cell. **Is there a way to detect which row the user is in?**

Comment: Is this code in your cell class or in your tableview class?

Comment: This code is in my tableView class @Paulw11

Comment: I would suggest that you add a property to your tableviewcell class that holds a reference to the data model object that it relates to and move the UITextViewDelegate methods into the tableviewcell class.  Then, implement a protocol that allows the cell to notify the view controller that text has changed, or whatever. The view controller can access the data model property directly from the cell and doesn't need to know about row numbers.  Storing row numbers is troublesome if the table can be re-ordered (rows deleted, inserted or moved)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using the tag property present on all UIView subclasses.

```
internal func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let cell:CustomCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomCell"){
         cell.textView.tag = indexPath.row

    }
}

internal func textViewDidBeginEditing(textView: UITextView){
    let row = textView.tag
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, Alex! Now that I think about it more, I can't use the question I posted because my end goal needs something else. If you have time, please look at the new question I just posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36903652/getting-data-from-all-tableviewcells . I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2):

You can check it right in your cellForRow method using blocks:

```
internal func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let cell:CustomCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomCell"){
         cell.editingDidBeginHandler = { [self weak], text
            //do your stuff, save index path, or tag or something else.
        }

    }
}
```

Inside your UITableViewCell subclass:

```
var editingDidBeginHandler:(()->())?

internal func textViewDidBeginEditing(textView: UITextView){
    if let handler = editingDidBeginHandler { editingDidBeginHandler() }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, Alex! Now that I think about it more, I can't use the question I posted because my end goal needs something else. If you have time, please look at the new question I just posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36903652/getting-data-from-all-tableviewcells . I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

You're right about the cell is not being selected when you type in a UITextField in a cell.

A quick way to accomplish this is to save the row as the UITextView's tag, then in the `textViewDidFinish`... delegate method create the index path with the section and the tag as the row.

Alternatively you can create a variable for each unique textView and then compare which textView you are using in the `textViewDidFinish` delegate method by comparing the two.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Alex! Now that I think about it more, I can't use the question I posted because my end goal needs something else. If you have time, please look at the new question I just posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36903652/getting-data-from-all-tableviewcells . I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

you can convert textView point to table view point to determine its index path.

```
func textViewDidBeginEditing(textView: UITextView) {
    let pointInTable = textView.convertPoint(textView.bounds.origin, toView: yourTableView)
    let textViewIndexPath = yourTableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(pointInTable)
    // do something else
}
```

This is assuming that you set text view delegate to table view.

If you set text view delegate to your custom cell, then you need to catch `textViewDidBeginEditing` function inside your custom cell and then pass the event to table view using protocol.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Alex! Now that I think about it more, I can't use the question I posted because my end goal needs something else. If you have time, please look at the new question I just posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36903652/getting-data-from-all-tableviewcells . I appreciate the help!