# Getting Data From all TableViewCells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextview

I am creating a flashcards app and right now I am creating the interface where the user creates the flashcards. I originally had it set up where the user could not add another card (add another UITableViewCell) until the current one had a term and definition. If the card was filled in, I would save the term and definition to a dictionary. What I realized part of the way through is that the user can go back to a previous cell and change the data in the cell and it would never be saved. My latest idea is to wait until the user finishes filling in all of the cells and then save the data. I can't seem to find a way to get the data of all of the cells.

What I have now in my **tableViewController**:

```
// MARK: Variables

var cards = [Int]()

var cardData = [String : String]()



// MARK: Actions

@IBAction func plusBarButtonItemPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    self.cards.append(self.cards.count + 1)

    let insertionIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: self.cards.count - 1, inSection: 0)

    tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([insertionIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)

}


@IBAction func doneBarButtonItemPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    // Save each cell into cardData [termTextView.text : definitionTextView.text]

}



// MARK: Functions

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return self.cards.count
}
```

And here is what I have now in my **custom tableViewCell**

```
// MARK: Outlets

@IBOutlet var termTextView: UITextView!

@IBOutlet var definitionTextView: UITextView!
```

Again, my question: **How can I get the text inside of the textViews inside all of the tableViewCells into a dictionary when a button (save) is pressed?**

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A tableView should not store data.  Data should be kept in your model (a data structure or data structures which hold your data independent of the tableView).  You should have this so that when cells scroll off of the screen and then back on, you can restore the data that is in them.

When the user enters data into a cell, you should immediately update your model.

When the save button is pressed, you should save your data from your model to a more permanent location (a file, Core Data, SQL database).

---

First, let's define a protocol for a `CardHandler`:

```
protocol CardHandler {
    func totalCards() -> Int
    func writeTerm(term: String, forCard cardNum: Int)
    func writeDefinition(definition: String, forCard cardNum: Int)
    func readTermForCard(cardNum: Int) -> String?
    func readDefinitionForCard(cardNum: Int) -> String?
    func addCard() -> Int
    func removeCardNum(cardNum: Int)
}
```

Next, define a class to be your model:

```
class Cards: CardHandler {
    struct CardRecord {
        var term: String = ""
        var definition: String = ""
    }

    var cards = [CardRecord]()

    func totalCards() -> Int {
        return cards.count
    }

    func writeTerm(term: String, forCard cardNum: Int) {
        if cardNum < cards.count {
            cards[cardNum].term = term
        }
    }

    func writeDefinition(definition: String, forCard cardNum: Int) {
        if cardNum < cards.count {
            cards[cardNum].definition = definition
        }
    }

    func readTermForCard(cardNum: Int) -> String? {
        if cardNum < cards.count {
            return cards[cardNum].term
        }
        return nil
    }

    func readDefinitionForCard(cardNum: Int) -> String? {
        if cardNum < cards.count {
            return cards[cardNum].definition
        }
        return nil
    }

    func addCard() -> Int {
        cards.append(CardRecord())
        return cards.count - 1
    }

    func removeCardNum(cardNum: Int) {
        if cardNum < cards.count {
            cards.removeAtIndex(cardNum)
        }
    }

    func convertToDictionary() -> [String: String] {
        var dict = [String: String]()

        for card in cards {
            dict[card.term] = card.definition
        }

        return dict
    }
}
```

---

In order to be notified when the user has modified a textField, make your `CustomTableViewCell` class be a UITextViewDelegate:

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITextViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var termTextView: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var definitionTextView: UITextView
    weak var cardHandler: CardHandler?

    var rowInTable = 0   // set this in cellForRowAtIndexPath to indexPath.row

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        termTextView.delegate = self
        definitionTextView.delegate = self
    }

    func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) {
        let text = textView.text

        if textView == termTextView {
            cardHandler?.writeTerm(text, forCard: rowInTable)
        } else if textView == definitionTextView {
            cardHandler?.writeDefinition(text, forCard: rowInTable)
        }
    }
 }
```

In your `UITableViewController`, have a property to contain your model:

```
var cards = Cards()
```

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, assign `cards` as the `cardHandler` for the `cell`:

```
let cell = dequeReusableCell ... as CustomTableViewCell
cell.rowInTable = indexPath.row
cell.cardHandler = cards
cell.contentView.termTextView.text = cards.readTermForCard(indexPath.row) ?? ""
cell.contentView.defintionTextView.text = cards.readDefinitionForCard(indexPath.row) ?? ""
```

For `numberOfRowsInSection`:

```
return cards.totalCards()
```

For `plusBarButtonItemPressed`:

```
@IBAction func plusBarButtonItemPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    let newCardNum = cards.addCard()
    let insertionIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: newCardNum, inSection: 0)
    tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([insertionIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
}
```

---

To get your cards as a dictionary, call `cards.convertToDictionary()` which returns a `[String: String]` dictionary with the `term` as the *key* and the `definition` as the *value*.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, vacawama! I need a bit of help understanding how you set up the model. I am able to get the text of the textView and its rowInTable. What I am not sure of, however, is how to save the term and definition textViews to the CardRecord. I can see CardRecord.init(term, definition), but I'm not sure how to save the term and definition for the correct rowInTable. Please advise!

Comment: I added a lot more detail.  I wrote this off the top of my head, so there may be a few typos.  I think you can get the gist of it though.

Comment: I'll take a look at this tomorrow. I appreciate all of your time!

Comment: Ok, I got everything to work! I did, however, run into two problems when getting the cards ready to send to Parse. First, I can't seem to convert the CardRecords into a dictionary. I plan on sending the data to parse using a dictionary(term:definition). Second (you may not know the answer to this), When the user types in the last term to definition and taps the done button (this is where the code will be sent to Parse), the textView that still is in edit mode doesn't write the data to the CardRecord. I tried coding customTableViewCell().endEditing(true), but no luck. Any ideas there?

Comment: Great!  I'm glad you got it to work.  You might want to implement `textViewDidChange` instead of `textViewDidEndEditing`.  It will get called every character, but you shouldn't miss anything that way.  I'll write you a quick routine to return a dictionary.

Comment: Good idea! I'm assuming you mean that I could constantly write to the term to definition using textViewDidChange and will be on the lookout for the routine tomorrow!

Comment: I updated the answer.  Yes, you could constantly update the term or definition as the user types.

Comment: convertToDictionary is working with one caveat. When the data is uploaded to parse, the dictionary is not ordered in the way I sent them. It will place the dictionary with the last term or definition edited first. For example, I type in "Term 1" and "Definition 1", then "Term 2" and "Definition 2". It will show up as {"Term 2":"Definition 2","Term 1":"Definition 1"}. I'm assuming that there is a way to access the card's rowInTable and sort it before upload beginning with row 0, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Dictionaries are unordered in Swift.  Even if you construct them in a particular order, it won't be stored that way.  When you upload it to parse, are you sending it as a Dictionary? If so, I'm not sure what to tell you.

Comment: I am uploading them as a dictionary, but is the least of my worries if it isn't stored 0 - infinity! I was just wondering if there was a way that I couldn't find.

Comment: I am also trying to get deleting a cell to work and it keeps giving me an error. I use this code in commitEditingStyle: tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
            
            cards.cards.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            
            cards.removeCardNum(indexPath.row)
            
            self.tableView.reloadData()

Comment: When deleting a row, the model should be updated first before calling `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` or you'll get an inconsistency error.  I would recommend `cards.removeCardNum(indexPath.row); tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath, withRowAnimation: .Fade); self.tableView.reloadData()`.

Comment: I just had to call self.tableView.beginUpdates() and self.tableView.beginUpdates() at the beginning and end of the function. Thanks for all of your help! I have another question and you may know the answer to it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36970265/calling-endediting-on-a-uiview. Thanks again!