# Calling endEditing on a UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextview

I have a tableView with two UITextViews. The user can add as many cells as they want by tapping on a "+" button. The tableView starts out with one row (cell). Lets say the user adds some information to the two textViews and then taps the plus button and scrolls to get to it. I call this function to dismiss the keyboard when a user scrolls so it isn't in the way:

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    self.view.endEditing(true)

}
```

Now, the keyboard disappears and the user goes to tap on the second row's text field. The tableView jumps up (I think to accommodate the keyboard), but the textField can't be edited (no cursor and keyboard doesn't appear). If I go back up to the first row (row 0), the keyboard appears and I can edit the textView. **Why is this happening?**

Comment: what happens if you call resignFirstResponder for the first textView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a property on scrollView subclasses (e.g TableViews)

```
tableView.keyboardDismissMode = .OnDrag
```

Once the user begins a descending drag it dismisses the keyboard

Comment: I am now noticing an error when I call that code in viewDidLoad. I get ~~ -[UIWindow endDisablingInterfaceAutorotationAnimated:] called on <UITextEffectsWindow: 0x79f77590; frame = (0 0; 320 480); opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x79f778f0>> without matching -beginDisablingInterfaceAutorotation. Ignoring. ~~ I looked this up online and none of the solutions got rid of the error. Any ideas?

Comment: No idea! However If you are using storyboard, you can set it in the attributes inspector ScrollView -> Keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

scrollViewDidScroll calls everytime the tableview moves, so when "The tableView jumps up (I think to accommodate the keyboard)" it also calls and close the keyboard. You should add there some confines or put endEditing code in the other place.